# Objects disappear when adding boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers

I am following an example from a book using Boolean modifier to cut hole in an object. I have two 3D objects overlapping and when I apply "difference" operation, the first object disappears. It's only one edge of the first object that's causing this problem- when I move the second object to other edges it works.

I am very new to Blender, is there anyway I can attach my Blender file for all to see?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: the most common pitfalls for boolean problems are, in my experience: using objects without any depth, normals not outside on both objects, negative scale that make normals seem outside while thay are inside...

Comment: This is the file, can someone please have a look and see why the cabin disappears when the Boolean modifier is added to the cabin and cube on RHS.[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=646" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/646/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the boolean operation fails is because you have duplicated geometry.

Enter edit mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> to Select All, then press the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> and type **Remove Doubles**.

[image]

The boolean should work now as expected:

[image]

\

Comment: Thank you. That works, although I don't understand how the geometry got doubled in the first place.

Comment: Remove doubles has gone in Blender 2.8+ .. use Merge By Distance
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123185/2-8-remove-doubles-has-changed-to-merge-by-distance
Caveat.. I'm learning.  I may well be wrong.