# 2.8 remove doubles has changed to Merge by Distance

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode

I'm using 2.8 
Is there no default short key combo to remove duplicates now?

I see that I can quickly add a shortcut for it - but it seems to me that it's something that should be in the mesh (w) menu. I use it all the time.

Thanks!

Comment: Try checking in the vertex menu 

Comment: Yeah, just did. Gosh, I'm sorry.

Comment: You're good! happy blendering and have fun with 2.8

Answer (score 23):

As of writing this answer, the option is <s>not present in Blender, or at least not searchable through <kbd>F3</kbd> and buried somewhere deep. What works instead, is</s> merging by distance by either of these methods:

(**remember** to first select at least two vertices: at least one will be kept, while those, that are too close to kept vertices (depending on the setting), will be removed)

1. From the *Mesh* menu select *Clean up* and then *Merge by distance*.
2. **[No longer in 2.90.1]** From the *Vertex* menu select *Merge Vertices* and then *by distance.*
3. From the context menu (right mouse button by default) select *Merge Vertices* and then *by distance*.
4. **Press <kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>B</kbd> keys.** [before 2.90.1 <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>B</kbd> keys.]

**A panel with settings will appear on bottom left:**

[image: Blender 2.8 collapsed Merge by Distance panel]

After clicking it, it will expand:

[image: expanded merge by distance dialog box]

On bottom you should see the number of removed vertices, depending on current setting:

[image: status message indicating number of removed vertices]

**Step-by-step example**

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, then <kbd>G</kbd> for a new *general file*.
2. Make sure the cube is selected.
3. Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter *edit mode*
4. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all vertices.
5. Click on a vertex.
6. Press <kbd>G</kbd> twice, and slide the vertex as far to another vertex as possible, so they both occupy the same position, confirm by clicking.
7. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices (to make sure both vertices in the same spot are selected)
8. Press <kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>B</kbd> to *merge by distance*. Regardless of the setting, at least one vertex will be removed which should be confirmed by a status bar message: [image: status message indicating number of removed vertices]
9. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all vertices again.
10. Click on the vertex that had a *"duplicate"* on the same position.
11. Either press <kbd>G</kbd> to start moving the vertex and see all edges are connected to just this one, and the other is gone or <kbd>H</kbd> to hide the vertex and see there's no second vertex at the same spot.

[image: animated screen capture of the step-by-step example]

**Beware**, that this will remove not only vertices that have the exact same coordinates, but also those that are within **0.0001m** of each-other. You can decrease this value to as low as **0.000001m**.

Thanks to the comments from Hikariztw and JtheNinja, I investigated the issue and indeed the old *remove doubles* worked exactly the same.
In Blender 2.79 the merge distance seemed to default to zero:

[image: Blender 2.79 remove doubles settings]

but after clicking the input field it would reveal that the **0.000** was just a rounded view of an actual non-zero value:

[image: old merge distance input after clicking on it]

In both cases (Blender 2.79 and Blender 2.8) the default value is **0.0001m** and the minimum value is **0.000001m** (in Blender 2.79 you have to go to scene settings and set metric system for length in order to see 1 micrometer instead of **0.000001** without a unit).

Comment: The **Beware** part is the original behavior that *remove double/merge in distance* operator do. The name changing is mainly to inform people how this is work in practices.

Comment: To further clarify, this IS the remove doubles tool. It's the same tool under the hood, just with a new name and UI location.

Comment: Could you update your answer to reflect the behavior in 2.91? I am unable to perform this once simple operation (mesh > clean up > merge by distance does not delete vertices that I know are overlapping)

Comment: @MicroMachine I checked in 2.91 and everything works as expected, so I decided to add a clarification, that vertices have to be selected and a step-by-step example how to use this feature. If you still have problems, consider asking a new question with your specific problem.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusvonBroady . I was extruding a text and then converting to mesh and the front, back and edges of each letters was disconnected. If the issue happens again I will make a Q.

Answer (score 3):

Blender 2.8 is in development. It's an unfinished alpha product constantly changing hour after hour. So if you're not prepared to constantly change with it, consider waiting for the 2.80 release.

---

For now, the default keymap is one of the things currently being worked on. You can follow the advancement  [on the tracker here](https://developer.blender.org/T55162). There is also a list of shortcut being made [here](https://developer.blender.org/T55194).

If you can't find a function used to be called via an obsolete shortcut, you can try to search it via the search menu (now bound to <kbd>F3</kbd>), or watch in the different menus in the viewport's header:
[image: viewport's header]

BTW, it seems to be in the "Context menu" (<kbd>W</kbd>, previously called "Specials menu") in today's build. But you have to be in vertex selection, as it's an operation on vertices and the new context menu is meant to show different tools according to the context:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In edit mode, select Mesh>Clean Up>Remove Doubles

Comment: Add an image to illustrate this.

Comment: Where in the view does it say how many vertices were removed? Can't find it.